# External repo cannot find SDL.h in Bazel

Tags: bazel

I am trying to run a successful build on my project using Bazel. Currently, I have the following external libraries I define in the following BUILD file:

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")
load("@bazel_skylib//lib:selects.bzl", "selects")

package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

exports_files(
    [
        "ggml.h",
        "ggml.c",
        "whisper.h",
        "whisper.cpp",
    ] + glob(["examples/*.cpp"]) + glob(["examples/*.h"]),
)

HEADERS = [
    "ggml.h",
    "whisper.h",
]

EXAMPLE_HEADERS = [
    "examples/common-sdl.h",
    "examples/common.h",
    "examples/dr_wav.h",
]

CFLAGS = [
    "-fexceptions",
    "-Wall",
    "-O3",
    "-std=c11",
    "-fPIC",
    "-pthread",
]

CXXFLAGS = [
    "-fexceptions",
    "-Wall",
    "-O3",
    "-std=c++11",
    "-fPIC",
    "-pthread",
]

cc_library(
    name = "common",
    srcs = ["examples/common.cpp"],
    hdrs = EXAMPLE_HEADERS,
    copts = CXXFLAGS + selects.with_or({
        "//conditions:default": [],
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:linux_x86_64": [
            "-mavx",
            "-mavx2",
            "-mfma",
            "-mf16c",
            "-msse3",
        ],
    }),
    linkopts = selects.with_or({
        "//conditions:default": [],
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin": [
            "-framework",
            "Accelerate",
        ],
    }),
)

cc_library(
    name = "common-sdl",
    srcs = ["examples/common-sdl.cpp"],
    hdrs = EXAMPLE_HEADERS,
    copts = CXXFLAGS + selects.with_or({
        "//conditions:default": [],
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:linux_x86_64": [
            "-mavx",
            "-mavx2",
            "-mfma",
            "-mf16c",
            "-msse3",
        ],
    }),
    linkopts = selects.with_or({
        "//conditions:default": [],
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin": [
            "-framework",
            "Accelerate",
        ],
    }),
    deps = ["@com_github_libsdl_sdl2//:SDL"],
)

cc_library(
    name = "ggml",
    srcs = ["ggml.c"],
    hdrs = HEADERS,
    copts = CFLAGS + selects.with_or({
        "//conditions:default": [],
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:linux_x86_64": [
            "-mavx",
            "-mavx2",
            "-mfma",
            "-mf16c",
            "-msse3",
        ],
    }),
    linkopts = selects.with_or({
        "//conditions:default": [],
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin": [
            "-framework",
            "Accelerate",
        ],
    }),
)

cc_library(
    name = "whisper",
    srcs = ["whisper.cpp"],
    hdrs = HEADERS + EXAMPLE_HEADERS,
    copts = CXXFLAGS + selects.with_or({
        "//conditions:default": [],
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:linux_x86_64": [
            "-mavx",
            "-mavx2",
            "-mfma",
            "-mf16c",
            "-msse3",
        ],
    }),
    linkopts = selects.with_or({
        "//conditions:default": [],
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin": [
            "-framework",
            "Accelerate",
        ],
    }),
    deps = [":ggml"],
)
```

where `@com_github_libsdl_sdl2` is built using the following BUILD file:

```
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:defs.bzl", "cmake", "configure_make")

package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

filegroup(
    name = "all_srcs",
    srcs = glob(["**"]),
)

cc_library(
    name = "include",
    hdrs = glob(["include/**"]),
    strip_include_prefix = "include",
)

COPTS = [
    "-fPIC",
    "-pthread",
    "-O3",
]

cmake(
    name = "SDL",
    cache_entries = {
        "CMAKE_C_FLAGS": "-fPIC",
        "CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES": "x86_64;arm64",
        "CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET": "10.14",
        "CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE": "ON",
        "CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR": "lib",
        "SDL_SHARED": "OFF",
        "SDL_JOYSTICK": "OFF",
        "SDL_HAPTIC": "OFF",
        "SDL_COCOA": "OFF",
        "SDL_METAL": "OFF",
        "SDL_TEST": "OFF",
        "SDL_RENDER": "OFF",
        "SDL_VIDEO": "OFF",
    },
    copts = COPTS,
    lib_source = ":all_srcs",
    linkopts = select({
        "//conditions:default": [],
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin": [
            "-Wl",
            "-framework",
            "CoreAudio,AudioToolbox",
        ],
    }),
    out_static_libs = select({
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:windows": [
            "libSDL2main.lib",
            "libSDL2.lib",
        ],
        "//conditions:default": [
            "libSDL2main.a",
            "libSDL2.a",
        ],
    }),
    targets = [
        "preinstall",
        "install",
    ],
)
```

However, when I try building my main library,

```
load("@bazel_skylib//lib:selects.bzl", "selects")
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")

package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

COPTS = [
    "-O3",
    "-pthread",
    "-std=c++11",
    "-fPIC",
    "-Wall",
] + selects.with_or({
    "//conditions:default": [],
    "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:linux_x86_64": [
        "-mavx",
        "-mavx2",
        "-mfma",
        "-mf16c",
        "-msse3",
    ],
})

cc_library(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cc"],
    hdrs = ["main.h"],
    copts = COPTS,
    defines = ["BAZEL_BUILD"],
    linkopts = selects.with_or({
        "//conditions:default": [],
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin": [
            "-framework",
            "AudioToolbox",
        ],
    }),
    deps = [
        "@com_github_ggerganov_whisper//:whisper",
        "@com_github_ggerganov_whisper//:common-sdl",
        "@com_github_libsdl_sdl2//:include"
    ]
)
```

I get the following error:

```
external/com_github_ggerganov_whisper/examples/common-sdl.h:3:10: fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found
#include <SDL.h>
```

I can see the `SDL.h` that is built (I think) in `bazel-cpp/external/com_github_ggerganov_whisper`, so I think the build is working, but for whatever reason, Bazel can't find this?

Hoping someone might have more insight here.

Comment: Does https://github.com/bazelregistry/sdl2 work for you?